# Using two entity sets in single table

Tags: sapui5

I have a normal table inside smart table. Inside normal table, I have 2 columns for order and operation.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="table" entitySet="entityset1" >
    <Table>
        <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <header>
                            <Text text="{order}"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <header>
                            <Text text="{operation}"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>

        </columns>
    </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

My problem is, order is coming from entityset1 and operation in coming from entityset2. Is it possible to use two different entity sets in single table?

Answer (score 0):

If the entities have a navigation property and the OData service supports is you can use the $expand to get the data in a form you can use to bind to the table.

Look at 4.6 on [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)

Here is an example by [Atanu Mallik](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3559486) of it used in a table binding

If this is not supported on you service or you do not have access to change your service then in the controller you can read both entitysets and create a JSON array with your related data in it. Create a JSON model out of your JSON object and use that model to bind to your table. But this is not ideal

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116.html#loio96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116

Hopes this helps